# MSSQL Converting String to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a database table in SQL Server 2008 that has a column that has a date string in the following format:
m/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss  (7/11/2015 1:01:45 PM)

I am trying to convert to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss (2015-07-11 13:01:45)

I've tried using CAST and CONVERT, but nothing seems to work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Example:
`SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, DATE_TIME, 120), DATE_TIME FROM TB1` results in the following error:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Comment: I just tried casting your date string to datetime, and it worked (see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7d/40).  What exactly isn't working about it?  Do you get an error?  Is it coming up with the wrong date?

Comment: I updated my question to show the error I am receiving.

Comment: Just one more reason why you should use the proper data types to begin with...

Comment: Does your table have more than one row in it?  Are you *sure* that the error is coming from the date you've put in your post?  It could be any row in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into this before and it sucks. Very likely, you've got a value that can't be converted to a datetime, and you need to find it (or them). 
Try selecting where isdate(string column) = 0 and see if any rows show up. Fix them or exclude them.

Comment: Yup, this was the problem.  I had over 30k records, and maybe around one hundred of them had "NULL" values.  Like, not that the record value was empty, there was a literal; string value that said "NULL".  After excluding those values, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(max), CONVERT(datetime, '7/11/2015 1:01:45PM', 101), 120)
```

[Here](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/) are a lot of examples

Comment: The problem is that I have this date in string format:  7/11/2015 1:01:45 PM

Using convert doesn't actually get it into yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format.

Comment: @user3150002 look at my edited variant, just 2 convertions

Comment: The double-conversion is the way to go - but I wouldn't cast to nvarchar(max) - I'd limit it to whatever the max length produced by your chosen format is - like 20.  It always amazes me to find people storing formatted datetime values in data.  Bad juju!  Best of all, the currently stored format can't even be correctly indexed.

Comment: @Back:  Thanks for the suggestion, but I am still getting the same "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." error.

Comment: @user3150002 really?? show, how you try it. I don't beleive

Answer (score 1):

I had to convert from M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss AM/PM to Datetime. Please note my localtime is DD-MM-YYYY so I had to convert in that format before converting to Datetime. Field name to convert was "Valeur" in table NIF. Here is how I did it in SQL 2008:

```
CREATE TABLE #NIF (Valeur VARCHAR(25))

INSERT INTO #NIF (Valeur) VALUES 
    ('8/20/2015 1:11:31 AM'),
    ('8/19/2015 10:37:32 PM'),
    ('10/7/2015 8:51:37 PM'),
    ('9/8/2015 3:27:17 PM')

SELECT NIF.Valeur, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('PM',NIF.Valeur) = 0 
THEN CONVERT(datetime,substring(NIF.Valeur, P2.Pos + 1, P3.Pos - P2.Pos - 1) + '-'
+ RIGHT('0' + substring(NIF.Valeur, P3.Pos + 1, P4.Pos - P3.Pos - 3),8) + '-'
+ RIGHT('0' + substring(NIF.Valeur, P1.Pos + 1, P2.Pos - P1.Pos - 1),2) + ' ' 
+ RIGHT('0' + substring(NIF.Valeur, 1, P1.Pos-1),2))
--add 12 hours if PM
ELSE DATEADD(hour,12,CONVERT(datetime,substring(NIF.Valeur, P2.Pos + 1, P3.Pos - P2.Pos - 1) + '-'
+ RIGHT('0' + substring(NIF.Valeur, P3.Pos + 1, P4.Pos - P3.Pos - 3),8) + '-'
+ RIGHT('0' + substring(NIF.Valeur, P1.Pos + 1, P2.Pos - P1.Pos - 1),2) + ' ' 
+ RIGHT('0' + substring(NIF.Valeur, 1, P1.Pos-1),2)))
END

FROM #NIF AS NIF (nolock)    
cross apply (select (charindex('/', NIF.Valeur))) as P1(Pos)
cross apply (select (charindex('/', NIF.Valeur, P1.Pos+1))) as P2(Pos)
cross apply (select (charindex(' ', NIF.Valeur, P2.Pos+1))) as P3(Pos)
cross apply (select (charindex('M', NIF.Valeur, P3.Pos+1))) as P4(Pos)
WHERE CHARINDEX('M',NIF.Valeur) > 0 --(I had other values in the table with   proper format)
```

You just have to change the order of the elements to set your particular local time.

Results obtained

8/20/2015 1:11:31 AM ---> 2015-08-20 01:11:31.000

8/19/2015 10:37:32 PM ---> 2015-08-19 22:37:32.000

10/7/2015 8:51:37 PM ---> 2015-10-07 20:51:37.000

9/8/2015 3:27:17 PM ---> 2015-09-08 15:27:17.000